# SDL2: SDL function SDL_Delay() freezes program on quitting the program with SDL_QUIT

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

the code in question:

```c
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <math.h>

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 750;

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Event e;

    bool running = true;

    if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, &window, &renderer)) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }

    while (running) {
        Uint64 start = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
        SDL_PollEvent(&e);
        switch (e.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                SDL_Quit();
                break;
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        Uint64 end = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
        float elapsedMS = (end - start) / (float) SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() * 1000.0f;
        SDL_Delay(floor(16.666f - elapsedMS));
    }
}
```

The intended behavior is that the window closes normally on quitting the program. What happens is that the window freezes and must be forced to crash or close with task manager. Commenting out `SDL_Delay(floor(16.666f - elapsedMS));` makes the window quit as intended without problem. How do I fix this without removing the mentioned line?

Comment: `SDL_Quit();` un-initializes SDL, so it's wouldn't be surprising if it breaks `SDL_Delay`. Perhaps you wanted `return 0;` or `std::exit(0);`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat removing `SDL_Quit()` hasn't changed anything. Changing `SDL_Quit()` with what you've written also doesn't change anything. I've even gone as far as putting the last line in an if statement, only to be executed if  `running` is true. Nothing helps except commenting it out? It's very confusing.

Comment: Another problem I see is that tou need to move the `switch` into `while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {...}`. Your code assumes that you'll get exactly one event per main loop iteration, which isn't the case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh wow! That solved it. Thank you a lot. Do you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Nah. :) You can post one yourself if you want to.